# Autosave Notepad Command

Tags: script, notepad, autosave

Can we have a command for MS Windows Notepad which triggers Save after a few seconds or like 30 seconds or Save every time I close the document.
I need something that works like .LOG which logs the date and time when opening a document.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, how is the 2nd question/sentence relevant to autosave functionality? Regardless, Notepad is outdated, default, basic WIndows software and it's unlikely anyone will give you a solution for this, even though it might be possible with help of external apps. Why not just use Notepad++ or any other reasonable editor?

Comment: None of this makes sense to me at all about what you are asking.. and as @Destroy666 points out.. the first q and the second q seem to have nothing in common.

Comment: Use Notepad++ https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924388

Answer (score 1):

Text files are barely documents, and there is not a function in Notepad that supports any sort of auto save or writing to text files based on actions in the software.

Comment: The notepad app is little more than a Win32 text/edit control with a few extra bells and whistles.  Microsoft has intentionally left this space vacant for other applications.  Trust me, any programmer on that team could easily add common features but aren't tasked to do so.  Use another editor.